# How to create one folder to store images from a website scrape

Tags: python, image, web-scraping, directory

I have written the following code to extract images for each product from a website scrape. I am very new to this and am unsure how to stop it creating a new folder for each product. Currently it creates a new folder called Whiteline Images inside the previous folder also titled whiteline images - easy enough to fix manually when its 5 products - not so much when I change it to 500+!! I know where in the code its doing this... just unsure how to fix it. Any help is appreciated!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

def imagedown(url,folder):
try:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), folder))
    except:
        pass    
    os.chdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), folder)) 
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    images = soup.findAll('img',{"src":True})

    for index, image in enumerate(images, start=1):
        if(image.get('src').startswith('https://imageapi.partsdb.com.au/api/Image')):
            link = (image.get('src'))
            name = f'{soup.find("div", {"class": "head2BR"}).text} ({index})'

            with open(name + '.jpg','wb') as f:
                im = requests.get(link) 
                f.write(im.content)
                print('Writing:', name)

imagedown('https://www.whiteline.com.au/product_detail4.php?part_number=KBR15', 'whiteline_images')
imagedown('https://www.whiteline.com.au/product_detail4.php?part_number=W13374', 'whiteline_images')
imagedown('https://www.whiteline.com.au/product_detail4.php?part_number=BMR98', 'whiteline_images')
imagedown('https://www.whiteline.com.au/product_detail4.php?part_number=W51210', 'whiteline_images')
imagedown('https://www.whiteline.com.au/product_detail4.php?part_number=W51211', 'whiteline_images')
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing directories, use `os.path.join` when writing the image to the directory:

```
import requests, os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def imagedown(url, folder):
   if not os.path.isdir(folder): #cleaner to use os.path.isdir when checking for folder existence
      os.mkdir(folder)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
   for index, image in enumerate(soup.findAll('img',{"src":True}), start=1): 
      if image.get('src').startswith('https://imageapi.partsdb.com.au/api/Image'):
          link = image.get('src')
          name = f'{soup.find("div", {"class": "head2BR"}).text} ({index})'
           with open(os.path.join(folder, name + '.jpg'), 'wb') as f: #join folder name to new image name
               im = requests.get(link) 
               f.write(im.content)
```

---

Edit: updated solution:

```
def imagedown(url, folder):
   if not os.path.isdir(folder): #cleaner to use os.path.isdir when checking for folder existence
      os.mkdir(folder)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
   for i, a in enumerate(soup.select('img:is(.mainman, .thumbbot)'), 1):
        name = soup.select_one('div.head2BR').text+f'({i})'
        with open(os.path.join(folder, name + '.jpg'), 'wb') as f: #join folder name to new image name
           im = requests.get(a['src']) 
           f.write(im.content)

imagedown('https://www.whiteline.com.au/product_detail4.php?part_number=KBR15', 'whiteline_images')
imagedown('https://www.whiteline.com.au/product_detail4.php?part_number=W13374', 'whiteline_images')
imagedown('https://www.whiteline.com.au/product_detail4.php?part_number=BMR98', 'whiteline_images')
imagedown('https://www.whiteline.com.au/product_detail4.php?part_number=W51210', 'whiteline_images')
imagedown('https://www.whiteline.com.au/product_detail4.php?part_number=W51211', 'whiteline_images')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  This definitely works to stop a new folder creating however now it only downloads one image per product not all as it was doing previously. I have no idea how to fix this :(

Comment: @LyndaHarmer Just to clarify: when you iterate over `soup.findAll('img',{"src":True})`, is it producing more than one image? Or is only one image getting written to the folder? Additionally, does your original script still work? My answer has only meaningfully changed the parts of your code that handle the folder and image creation.

Comment: My code downloaded approx 4 images per product.  When I changed it to what you have suggested it stopped creating a new folder but it only downloaded one image per product.  I created the  soup.findAll('img',{"src":True})  part of the code as it was finding all the images on the page (afterpay, Facebook logo etc).  This code just removed them from the results and gave me just the product images.

Comment: @LyndaHarmer Please see my recent edit, I added a solution which I have been able to run successfully on my machine. Please let me know how it works for you.

Comment: @LyndaHarmer Glad to help!